# Is there a way to test if VS Code is resolving my shell environment on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

When VS Code is started from Activities (i.e. via the UI), I receive an error message, "Unable to resolve your shell environment: Unexpected exit code from spawned shell (code 1, signal null)". This is happening because the last block in my rc file (zsh, not that it should matter here) is:

```sh
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null \
   && [ -n "$PS1" ] \
   && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] \
   && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]] \
   && [ -z "$TMUX" ] \
   && [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" != "vscode" ]]; then
  exec tmux
fi
```

I got the tmux-specific part of the guard [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113768/460319) and the Code-specific part [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134191/1014459). However, when Code is running the "small process to run (or 'resolve') the shell environment" described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_resolving-shell-environment-fails), `$TERM_PROGRAM` does not appear to be set, so `exec tmux` still runs, hence the error.

How can I detect that the environment resolver is running? Does it set any other variables that I can test?

**EDIT**: I realized I could just list the environment out to file in my rc, and I found a number of variables prefixed with `VSCODE_`, namely the following:

```
VSCODE_CODE_CACHE_PATH
VSCODE_CWD
VSCODE_IPC_HOOK
VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG
VSCODE_PID
```

Is testing for any of these reliable in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Checking the process tree](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021556/1014459) is a consistent and reliable way to do this in either scenario (integrated terminal or environment resolution process). Specifically, my `.zshrc` now ends as follows:

```sh
if ... (tmux conditions) \
   && ! pstree -s $$ | grep -wq code; then
  exec tmux
fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when launching VS Code from the dock on mac os.

Comment: @Jared I don't have access to an Apple machine, so I can't help you directly. A few ideas: 1) As a noted in the question edit, you can dump your environment to file from inside your shell init script. You might try inspecting that to see if you can find any variables set which serve your purpose. 2) I'm assuming you checked that `pstree` is installed, but if not, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11806). 3) I don't know the name of the `code` process on Mac OS. It may be different, and so the `grep` command would need to be changed. Please reply with any findings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wasn't able to find a solution that did not trigger when VS Code was launched from the dock. As a workaround, I use this to only use tmux when Terminal.app is started: `&& pstree -p $$ | grep Terminal.app | grep -qv grep;`. This is acceptable for me right now, but I'll notify here if I find a more full-featured solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's something like `NODE_OPTIONS...` in my ~/.zshrc file. I removed it and  vscode worked